# Are there any third party UI audio player libraries for embedding into an Android app?

Tags: android, audio

I'm developing a feature-rich Android application in Java that needs to include an audio player with a specific design. The player will be used in various places in the app, including in several activities and as a list item in the RecyclerView. It will play audio files from both the Internet and the device, as well as voice notes recorded by the user.

In this regard, I have a question: are there any ready-made third-party audio player libraries with a user interface (preferably customizable) that I could embed into my Android app? So that I don’t have to draw the buttons and slider myself, set the click listeners for the buttons, calculate the duration of the audio and update the position of the slider every second, manually configure services and notifications for background playback. Instead, I'd like to just add a player to the layout and feed it the audio I need and let it do the rest for me!

I know that there are many custom UI elements for a variety of purposes - for cropping an image, for displaying a calendar with colored markers, for entering a PIN code... But I have not yet found such a seemingly necessary element as a ready-made audio player! I will be very glad if you advise me such solutions.

Thank you in advance!